# Sending mail using default sender address

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to send a mail in my website. Now the problem is I dont want to type the from address, I wish to get the from address in textbox by default.

Below is the code i tried so far:

```
protected void btnMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
        Msg.From = lblFrom.Text;
        Msg.To = txtTo.Text;
        Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        Msg.Body = txtBody.Text;

        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "10.20.72.1";
        SmtpMail.Send(Msg);

        Msg = null;

        Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Mail sent thank you...'); if(alert){ window.location='SendMail.aspx'; }</script>");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me to get the senders e-mail Id automatically.

**Edited:**

I was just browsing on a way for it and i found some code in web.But i dont understand how to implement it in my code.
Below is the code :

```
WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
        WebMail.UserName = "your-user-name-here";
        WebMail.Password = "your-account-password";
        WebMail.From = "your-email-address-here";
```

Can i know how to implement this in my code.

Comment: Get their email from where exactly?  Their logged in credentials?

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: Ya and i wish to give the username and password for login in code behind.Is there a way?

Comment: Not problem Exactly i don't know how exactly to get the sender address by default.

Comment: @Maes save user's email address in session or use State Management to retain the email address. When you require just get from there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblFrom.Text = "youremail@gmail.com";
}
```

Comment: " i wish to get the **from** address in textbox by default."  Not seeing how this answers OP's question...

Comment: @tim sorry I fixed it ?

Comment: Based on OP's comments, they want to get the e-mail address from the logged in user.

Comment: yes I saw it if you need the email by default  you need to hardcode it somewhere!!!